# Lead acid (PbA) charger and fuel gauge

Tags: raspberry-pi, battery

I want a charger and SoC determiner ic/with example (sample) circuit or a product for a Lead acid (PbA) battery 12V/65Ah. Which can send the SoC through a I2C port to my microcontroller (Raspberry Pi).